# python find max value and print first 5 lines of file

Tags: python

I am trying a program,where i have a directory and having  list of text files,if I find "color=" then it will find the fuzzy value of the 'filename' and 'starting line of file',so:

---

I need to :
find the max value of fuzzy value and need to find the first 5 lines for the file having max value

I did a coding where it can find all the fuzzy value but i dont know how to find max value and then print the first 5 files having maximum fuzzy value.Please help!

```
import os
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

path = r'C:\Python27' 
data = {}


for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
    dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
        with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "color=" in part:
                        print part
                        string1= "Filename:", dir_entry_path
                        print(string1)
                        string2= "Start line of file:", list(my_file)[0]
                        print(string1)
                        string3=(fuzz.ratio(string1, string2))
                        print(string3)
```

And my output now looks as:

```
"color="
('Filename:', 'C:\\Python27\\maybeee.py')
('Filename:', 'C:\\Python27\\maybeee.py')
20
"color="
('Filename:', 'C:\\Python27\\mayp.py')
('Filename:', 'C:\\Python27\\mayp.py')
28
part.startswith('color='):
('Filename:', 'C:\\Python27\\mayp1.py')
('Filename:', 'C:\\Python27\\mayp1.py')
29
```

I need the output to be,considering example here max value is 29,so i need to print the first 5 lines of the file having the max value.Please help!Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: You're printing string1 twice, rather than printing string2

Comment: And at the moment you take it `list(my_file)[0]` does not contain first line of file but ... next line as `my_file` is an iterable.

Comment: Do you want the first 5 *lines* of the file that has (according to your criterion) the highest [fuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy/0.1) value, or the names of the 5 *files* with highest fuzzy value?

Comment: Does the string "color=" appear only once or not at all in your text files? Because if it appears several times on different lines, each file has multiple fuzzy values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attempts to reread the entire file again (at `list(myfile)[0]`), while there's an iterator going over it already. This is troublesome.

It would be better to store the 5 first lines (this is what you're asking, yes?) in a variable and then print them when your condition matches.

Also, you're printing `string1` twice.

Changing your loop to:

```
from collections import defaultdict
filenames2fuzz = defaultdict(list)

for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
    dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
    if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
        first5lines = []
        condition_matched_in_file = False
        with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
            for line_nbr, line in enumerate(my_file):
                if line_nbr < 5: 
                    first5lines.append(line)
                for part in line.split():
                    if "color=" in part:
                        print part
                        string1= "Filename:", dir_entry_path
                        print(string1)
                        condition_matched_in_file = True

                        fuzziness = fuzz.ratio(string1, first5lines[0])
                        filenames2fuzz[dir_entry_path].append(fuzziness)
                        print(fuzziness)
        if condition_matched_in_file:
            print('\n'.join(first5lines))

# Now that you have a dictionary that holds all filenames with 
# their fuzziness values, you can easily find the first 5 lines again
# of the file that has the best fuzziness value.

best_fuzziness_ratio = 0  # as far as I can tell, the docs indicate it is between 0 and 100
for k, v in filenames2fuzz.items():
    if max(v) > best_fuzziness_ratio:
        best_fuzzy_file = k
        best_fuzziness_ratio = max(v)
print('File {} has the highest fuzzy value '
    'of {}. \nThe first 5 lines are:\n'
    ''.format(best_fuzzy_file, best_fuzziness_ratio))
with open(best_fuzzy_file) as f:
    for i in range(5):
        print(f.readline())
```

There are a few more optimizations you could do (have a look at [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)) and without a better explanation of the problem (give details about the files you're looping over, list parts of their contents), this is the best I can do.

Comment: hi oliver please answer my new question,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612908/python-print-max-line-fuzzy-ratio-from-a-file you co