# python finding average fuzzy ratio of all lines

Tags: python

I am trying a code to find the average fuzzyratio of all the lines in the file with the word good:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from collections import defaultdict
with open(qwer.txt, 'r') as my_file:
     for line in my_file:
        for part in line.split():
          a=line
          b='good'
          fuzziness = fuzz.ratio(a,b)
          filenames2fuzz[line].append(fuzziness)

    best_fuzziness_ratio = 0 
    for k, v in filenames2fuzz.items():
        if max(v) > best_fuzziness_ratio:
            best_fuzzy_line = k
            best_fuzziness_line_ratio = max(v)
    average=v/n(v)#<-not sure 
    print average
```

how to print the average fuzzyratio of all lines with the word good and print the average?
please help!answers would be appreciated!

Comment: And your question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a memory-efficient solution, I would probably do something like that.

```
def good_ratio(a):
    return fuzz.ratio(a, 'good')

with open('qwer.txt', 'r') as my_file:
   my_sum, my_len = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file))
   print(my_sum/my_len)
```

Please note that this is a float division in python3 and you will need something like `my_sum/(float)my_len` in python2.

Also, you might want to filter the lines with 'good' (or maybe 'good ' or something else), for instance with `((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file if 'good' in i)`.

Comment: so your coding will check the entire line even with/without good and takes the average .is that so?

Comment: Yes. If you need the average of lines with 'good', use the trick I described afterwards.

Comment: ok,you are great programmer!thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're shooting for something like this:

```
 div = 0
 ratio_total = 0
 for line in my_file:
     for word in line:
           ratio = fuzz.ratio(word, 'good') # might want to use partial_ratio instead
           if ratio > 0: # or some threshold:
                ratio_total += ratio
                div += 1

  print("Average ratio: %s" % (ratio_total/div,))
```

I think what you want to do is go through each word in a line and compare each word to "good".  This should get you close?